# Spring boot application deployed in STS works fine, but not in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have Spring-boot application which is built with Maven. When I deploy it with STS( *Run as Spring Boot App*) it works fine, but when I use IntelliJ Idea it doesn't work.

There is no error in log during deployment process. But when I try to refresh page I got this:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback. Mon Aug 04 14:48:38 CEST 2014 There was an
>   unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

I've added Spring module to project. After I added this I have added some XML's *XML based configurations* and my `Application.java` class to *Code based configurations*.

I've changed logging to `FINEST` and noticed that when I reload page there are some differences in logs between working and not working version.

**Not working version**

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'layouts/default'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp] are [/**]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp] are {}
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@29a502a0] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp] is: -1
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Ignoring invalid resource path [WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - No matching resource found - returning 404
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /error
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] - Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
TRACE [class which inherates from UrlBasedViewResolver] - Cached view [error]
TRACE [class which inherates from UrlBasedViewResolver] - Cached view [error]
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] - Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@758e2ae8] based on requested media type 'text/html'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@758e2ae8] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
```

**Working version**

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/default.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'layouts/default'
INFO [org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache] - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/css/bootstrap-fix.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /css/bootstrap-fix.css
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/css/bootstrap-fix.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/css/bootstrap-fix.css] are [/**]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/css/bootstrap-fix.css] are {}
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] are [/**]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] are {}
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] are [/**]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] are {}
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/css/bootstrap-fix.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@ff47cbc] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/css/bootstrap-fix.css] is: -1
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [css/bootstrap-fix.css] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [css/bootstrap-fix.css] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [css/bootstrap-fix.css] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [css/bootstrap-fix.css] against base location: class path resource [static/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Found matching resource: class path resource [static/css/bootstrap-fix.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Determined media type 'text/css' for class path resource [static/css/bootstrap-fix.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@ff47cbc] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] is: -1
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@ff47cbc] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] is: -1
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] against base location: class path resource [static/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Found matching resource: class path resource [static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Determined media type 'text/css' for class path resource [static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] against base location: class path resource [static/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Found matching resource: class path resource [static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Determined media type 'application/javascript' for class path resource [static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] are [/**]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] are {}
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@ff47cbc] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] is: -1
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Trying relative path [javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] against base location: class path resource [static/]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Found matching resource: class path resource [static/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] - Determined media type 'application/javascript' for class path resource [static/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js]
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
```

Class which is giving some error inherates from `UrlBasedViewResolver`, but I have no idea what can I do with that. `Cached view [error]` gives me no clue.

What might cause this problems?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention:

**STS 3.5.1**

**IntelliJ Idea 13.1**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a war file from intellij. (I suspect this due to the use of JSPs in your app). To make this work you would have to deploy the modified war to tomcat instead of the regular war file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STS has a number of Eclipse plugins that you won't find in IntelliJ.  To get a Spring Boot application running from IntelliJ, you need to create a Maven run configuration with the command "spring-boot:run" and make sure it points at the correct module, if your app has multiple modules in it.

Comment: Not sure why that would be needed? Never had a problem with an `Application` class and simply running it from within IntelliJ. No maven needed.

Comment: It's how I always run them in IntelliJ without a problem.  Never tried actually running the Application class directly.

Comment: It works fine, but I have no idea why. I didn't changed any configuration despite the fact I started it as maven configuration with `spring-boot:run` goal. Beforehand I was running `Application.java` as Spring application and it caused the problems...

Comment: same with Intellij IDEA 14.1 (my Application.class is not a valid Spring Boot Application class => not annotated...)

Comment: @PatrickGrimard With spring-boot:run are you able to debug too in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes.  You can create a separate run configuration for spring-boot:run with command line `spring-boot:run "-Drun.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"` then create a remote run configuration accepting the defaults.  Once done, launch the spring boot debug run configuration first and once it's ready, launch the remote run configuration and you'll be able to debug in IntelliJ.